# Drag Gesture Recognizer interfere with swipe Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a problem about gesture recognizer. I have two gesture recognizers in my view, one added to the background superview to swipe to change background color, the other one is added to a subview which could be dragged around.

The problem is the drag gesture is interfered with the swipe. When I drag the view around, in some case, drag operation will be recognized as a swipe and trigger the swipe operation. I don't want this, I just want swipe could be recognized after finish this drag operation. This situation is more often when I drag the subview around quickly. Every time during the drag, the swipe operation will be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your lesser `UIGestureRecognizer` with `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` and pass your recognizer that you want to be important to it.

```
UIView *subview = ....
[self addSubview:subview];

[self.gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:subview.gestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: I think this method is good and should work, however I used your method, and found that the swipe gesture, which refers to your self.gestureRecognizer can't recognize swipe at all.

Comment: It sounds like your subview is consuming all gesture events on the screen.  You may have to set up a delegate for your subview gesturerecognizer and override the delegate functions to set when they recognizer should recognize events.

Comment: Cool, I used this method, set the view controller as the swipe gestureRecognizer delegate, and add a notification for the drag gesture recognizer, when the drag finished, I post a notification, to set The Flag bool to YES, then the swipe gesture recognizer's delegate method can remove the block. How do you think about this? Cool solution, Thanks